# Android CameraX: ImageCapture a bit different than Preview

Tags: android, preview, android-camerax, image-capture

I develop app where I want to take photo only on the middle square but by keeping the preview on almost the whole screen [image]like in this picture.
However, the imageproxy, after a cropping, does not look like the previous image, the width and height are bigger.[image]

I notice that what I see with my app and with the device photo app is a bit different, my app seems to zoom a little.

What I've already try:

- `setViewPort` with the middle view size
- `setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)` to both ImageCapture and Preview
- add a TextureView or SurfaceView or even another Preview in replacement of the middle view. That was good but I lost the transparency
- one of the best solution was to add `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"` to the xml layout of the preview. But again I lost the transparency (the preview height was 4/3 higher than the width, and above and below, I had white banners.

So why the preview is different of the device camera's one ?
Do you know a solution to set the preview on the whole screen but keep only a square center image ?

Comment: Looks like the preview screen is 16:9 and the camera then takes 4:3 images. Try `scaleType="fitCenter"` for your preview TextureView and limit the width of the view to the width of the screen.

Comment: @GenError, actually it works like `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"` to the xml, the area of transparency is cropped

Comment: you can try solution in post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242315/how-to-crop-image-rectangle-in-camera-preview-on-camerax