# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.Display.getRotation()

Tags: android, android-camerax, scanning, google-mlkit

I am trying to implement Google MKit Library for QR Code Scan  .I am following [this tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/building-barcode-qr-code-scanner-for-android-using-google-ml-kit-and-camerax-220b2852589e)  It works fine on my phone. After I publish to playstore, it crashes on some phones.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.Display.getRotation()' on a null object reference

I believe  binding.previewView!!.display.rotationcall throws error.  It only happens on Play store version. It doesn't happen on debug mode.

```
 private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
private var cameraSelector: CameraSelector? = null
private var lensFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
private var previewUseCase: Preview? = null
private var analysisUseCase: ImageAnalysis? = null
private lateinit var binding: ActivityBarcodeScannerBinding

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_scanner)
    binding = ActivityBarcodeScannerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setupCamera()
}

private fun setupCamera() {
    //previewView = binding.previewView
    cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()
    ViewModelProvider(
        this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
    ).get(CameraXViewModel::class.java)
        .processCameraProvider
        .observe(this) { provider: ProcessCameraProvider? ->
            cameraProvider = provider
            if (isCameraPermissionGranted()) {
                bindCameraUseCases()
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                    PERMISSION_CAMERA_REQUEST
                )
            }
        }
}

private fun bindCameraUseCases() {
    bindPreviewUseCase()
    bindAnalyseUseCase()
}

private fun bindPreviewUseCase() {
    if (cameraProvider == null) {
        return
    }
    if (previewUseCase != null) {
        cameraProvider!!.unbind(previewUseCase)
    }

    previewUseCase = Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        .setTargetRotation(binding.previewView!!.display.rotation)
        .build()
    previewUseCase!!.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView!!.surfaceProvider)

    try {
        cameraProvider!!.bindToLifecycle(
            /* lifecycleOwner= */this,
            cameraSelector!!,
            previewUseCase
        )
    } catch (illegalStateException: IllegalStateException) {
        Log.e(TAG, illegalStateException.message ?: "IllegalStateException")
    } catch (illegalArgumentException: IllegalArgumentException) {
        Log.e(TAG, illegalArgumentException.message ?: "IllegalArgumentException")
    }
}
```

Comment: The preview view might be not ready yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57244526/why-view-display-returns-null

Comment: You don't need to set the target rotation for PreviewView. That's not necessary.

Comment: @ Xi 张熹 it crashes in android 10 if target rotation is not set.But it works well on android 13  without setting rotation

Answer (score 0):

I think it is required in old android version . So I added null checking and it solve the problem.

```
   if(binding.previewView?.display?.rotation != null){
            previewUseCase = Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                .setTargetRotation(binding.previewView.display.rotation)
                .build()
        }else{
            previewUseCase = Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                .build()
        }
```

Also make sure you are using same version  of android x camera

```
def camerax_version = "1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
```